# Identify twitter profiles have default image

Tags: twitter

All

I want to count my followers profile having the default twitter profile image.(in short not changes default image)
Ex.

[image]

Is that possible ? How?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible!

First find out your list of followers' IDs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

Then lookup your followers:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

You'll receive `"default_profile_image":true` for a follower if they have the default profile image.

For example if you query [your own Twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/ajaypatel_aj) using JSON: https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=ajaypatel_aj

You will see:

```
"default_profile_image":false
```

Or using XML: https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?screen_name=ajaypatel_aj

You will see:

```
<default_profile_image>false</default_profile_image>
```