# default_profile_image in twitter user

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to check if a user in twitter uses the default image profile. I found in the API this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners), which explaind that there exists a default_profile_image boolean field which define either a user uses a default pic or not. However, I didnt find in which class this default_profile_image picture can be found. Any idea?

I found that all default pics are having the following typo of url:

```
https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png
https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_bigger.png
```

So, I could check for image url name. How is it possible to check if the user url image contains the path substring https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images?

Answer (score 1):

User method isDefaultProfileImage().

```
/**
 * Tests if the user has not uploaded their own avatar
 *
 * @return if the user has not uploaded their own avatar
 */
boolean isDefaultProfileImage();
```

see [User.java in twitter4j](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=79s1uXOMMf6t27-y7XCT45C9De8&cid=Xby4IKQCDbw&s=%22isDefaultProfileImage%22&pp=0&fl=Java&fd=mdef&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=3205&mp,=0&projSelected=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1#L96)

Comment: User user = twitter.showUser((id));
user.isDefaultProfileImage();
It does not find any isDefaultProfileIMage.

Comment: @FereRes you are right , seems like this is not available here :/. did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10556886/1737819 ?

Comment: Yea I found it, but I though that is a little bit silly, to found first a list of followers. Finally I did mannually but checking the profile image url. It seems when the user have default image the url is always https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/

Comment: Basically I know that there exists two methods default_profile and default_profile_image, however, I am not sure in which object they ca be found.

Comment: I am not capable to find in which object it refers here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

Comment: Well, since isDefaultProfileImage isn't available:(, then could try to get default image from url. With [TwitterImpl](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.html) object , call for it [showUser method](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.html#showUser(long)) to get the user. Then for the user make: boolean has_default_profile_image = (-1 != user.getProfileImageUrl().indexOf("default_profile_image") ). What do you think?